# GDocs spreadsheet conditional sum

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

How to sum every 6th row in google spreadsheet?

```
=SUMIF(A1:A100; MOD(CURRENT_ROW_NUMBER, 6) = 0;A1:A100)
```

But I have no idea how to get current tested row number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(MOD(ROW(A1:A100); 6) = 0; A1:A100; 0)))
```

Comment: Thx a lot :) It saved me so much time ;)